# How to reload to same page in Single Page Application using Angular 4 and Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic3

Here I first Fill up User details then submit, then otp page loads. I want to reload OTP page after user enters an invalid OTP so that he can enter OTP once gain. I am unable to reload to same page. Please help me by providing the changes in my code. I am new in Ionic3 and Angular4. Please let me know where I am getting wrong.

signup.html

```
   <ion-content padding>            
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"></script>

        <div class="container1">
            <div class="centerLogo"><h1><a href="#"><img src="img/logo.jpg"  /></a></h1></div>
        <ion-list>
            <form  #fm = "ngForm" (ngSubmit)="myHome(fm)" [formGroup]="myform" *ngIf="!showpage">

            <div *ngIf="!generateOtp">
              <ul id="tabs">
              <li (click)="showpage=false"><a id="tab2">Registration Form</a></li>
              </ul>
              <div class="form-group" id="tab2C"  >

              <ion-item>
              <ion-input type="text" formControlName="name" [(ngModel)]="userInfo.name" placeholder="Name" name="name" id="name" spellcheck="false" autocapitalize="off"></ion-input>
              </ion-item>

              <p *ngIf="!isValid('name')" danger padding-left>Invalid Name</p>

              <ion-item>
              <ion-input type="email" formControlName="email" [(ngModel)]="userInfo.email" placeholder="Email" name="email" id="email" spellcheck="false" autocapitalize="off"></ion-input>
              </ion-item>

              <p *ngIf="!isValid('email')" danger padding-left>Invalid Email</p>

              <ion-item>
              <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="userInfo.mobileNo" formControlName="mobileNo" placeholder="Mobile Number" name="mobileNo" id="mobileNo" pattern="[0-9]*" minlength="10" maxlength="10" #mobileNo></ion-input>
              </ion-item>

              <p *ngIf="!isValid('mobileNo')" danger padding-left>Invalid mobileNo</p>

              <ion-item>
                <ion-input type="password" formControlName="pin" [(ngModel)]="userInfo.pin" placeholder="Enter Pin" name="pin" id="pin" spellcheck="false" minlength="4" maxlength="6" autocapitalize="off"></ion-input>
              </ion-item>

              <ion-item>
                 <ion-input type="password" formControlName="confirmPin"[(ngModel)]="userInfo.confirmPin"  placeholder="Confirm Pin" name="confirmPin" id="confirmPin" minlength="4" maxlength="6" spellcheck="false" autocapitalize="off"></ion-input>
              </ion-item>

              <p *ngIf="myform.hasError('mismatchedpins')" danger padding-left>Pin mismatch</p>

              <div class="btnRow">
                  <button class="loginBtn" id="phoneBtn" ion-button color="footer" type="button" [disabled]="!myform.valid" (click)="generateOtpFrommobileNo(mobileNo._value)" full>Continue</button>
              </div>
              <p></p>

            </div>
           </div>
            <div *ngIf="generateOtp">
              <ul id="tabs">
              <li><a id="tab2">Enter OTP</a></li>
              </ul>
              <div class="form-group" id="tab2C">
                <div class="form-group">
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-input type="number"  formControlName="otp"  placeholder="Enter OTP" name="otp" id="otp" minlength="6" maxlength="6"></ion-input>
                </ion-item>
                <div class="btnRow">
                    <button class="loginBtn" id="phoneBtn" ion-button color="footer" type="submit" [disabled]="!myform.valid" full>Continue</button>
                </div>
                <p></p>
                <!-- <button  ion-button small clear color="dark" [disabled]="!myform.valid" type="submit" full>Continue</button> -->
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
      </form>
        <button ion-button small clear color="light" (click)="homePage()">Log In</button>

        </ion-list>
        </div>            
      </ion-content>
```

signup.ts

```
    import { Component, Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
    import { RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
    import 'rxjs/operator/delay';
    import 'rxjs/operator/mergeMap';
    import 'rxjs/operator/switchMap';
    import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
    import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
    import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
    import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
    import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";


    @IonicPage()
    @Component({
      selector: 'page-signup',
      templateUrl: 'signup.html',
    })
    export class SignupPage implements OnInit {
        myform: FormGroup;
        userInfo: {name: string, email: string, mobileNo: string, pin: string, confirmPin: string, otp: string} = {name: '', email: '', mobileNo: '', pin: '', confirmPin: '', otp: ''};

     fm: FormGroup;
    //  myform:FormGroup;
      username:string = '';
      name:string = '';
      email:string = '';
      titleAlert:string = 'This field is required';
      pin: string;

      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private http: Http, public formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

        this.myform = formBuilder.group({
          //  username : [null, Validators.required],
            name : [null, Validators.required],
            email: ['', Validators.email],
            mobileNo: [null, Validators.required],
            pin: ['', Validators.required],
            confirmPin: ['', Validators.required],
            otp: ['', Validators.required],
          }, {validator: this.matchingpinsValidator('pin', 'confirmPin')});                                  
      }

      ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log('ionViewDidLoad SignupPage');
      }

      otpPage(){
        this.navCtrl.push(OtpPage);
     }

     homePage(){
      this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
    }

    ngOnInit(): any {
        this.myform = this.formBuilder.group({
          'name': ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(20), this.nameValidator.bind(this)]],
          'mobileNo': ['', this.mobileNoValidator.bind(this)],
          'email': ['', [Validators.required, this.emailValidator.bind(this)]],
          'pin':[],
          'confirmPin': ['', [Validators.required, this.matchingpinsValidator.bind(this)]],
          otp :[]
         //  'otp': ['', [Validators.required, this.otpValidator.bind(this)]],
        }, {validator: this.matchingpinsValidator('pin', 'confirmPin')});
      }

      onSubmit() {
        console.log('submitting form');
      }

      isValid(field: string) {
        let formField = this.myform.get(field);
        return formField.valid || formField.pristine;
      }

      nameValidator(control: FormControl): {[s: string]: boolean} {
        if (!control.value.match("^[a-zA-Z ,.'-]+$")) {
          return {invalidName: true};
        }
      }

      mobileNoValidator(control: FormControl): {[s: string]: boolean} {
        if (control.value !== '') {
          if (!control.value.match('\\(?\\d{3}\\)?-? *\\d{3}-? *-?\\d{4}')) {
            return {invalidmobileNo: true};
          }
        }
      }

      otpValidator(control: FormControl): {[s: string]: boolean} {
        if (control.value !== '') {
          if (!control.value.match('\\(?\\d{3}\\)?-? *\\d{3}-? *-?\\d{4}')) {
            return {invalidotp: true};
          }
        }
      }

      emailValidator(control: FormControl): {[s: string]: boolean} {
        if (!(control.value.toLowerCase().match('^[a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,15})$'))) {
          return {invalidEmail: true};
        }
      }

      matchingpinsValidator(pinKey: string, confirmPinKey: string) {
        return (group: FormGroup): {[key: string]: any} => {
          let pin = group.controls[pinKey];
          let confirmPin = group.controls[confirmPinKey];
          if(confirmPin.value != ''){
            if (pin.value !== confirmPin.value) {
                return {
                mismatchedpins: true
                };
            }
          }
        }
      }

     showpage = false;
    generateOtp = false;
    onSelect() {
        console.log(this.generateOtp);
        this.generateOtp = !this.generateOtp;
    }

    generateOtpFrommobileNo(mobileNoEnter){
            let headers = new Headers({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
             });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        let baseurl = 'http://retail.business.ticket/maintain3/rest/transaction/generateOtp/';
        let perfix = mobileNoEnter;
        this.generateOtp = true;
        let finalUrl = baseurl + perfix;
        console.log(options);
          this.http.get(finalUrl, options)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                console.log(data);
                if (data){
                    alert(data);
               //     alert("Going to OTP Page");           
                }
                else{
                 alert("Please check your info");
                }
            },
            err => {
                console.log("ERROR:  quote-service:myHome1()")
                console.log(err);
                alert(err._body);
            }
        );
    }

    myHome1(fm:NgForm) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {

                    });
        }

        myHome(fm:NgForm) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                            let headers = new Headers({
                                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        });
                         console.log(fm.value["name"]);
                       var  data = {
                            "name":fm.value["name"],
                            "email":fm.value["email"],
                            "mobileNo":fm.value["mobileNo"],
                            "pin":fm.value["pin"],
                            "confirmPin":fm.value["confirmPin"],
                            "otp":fm.value["otp"],
                            "groupId":"5" };

                            let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
                            console.log(data);
                            this.http.post('http://retail.business.ticket/maintain3/rest/transaction/register', data, options)
                                .map(res => res.json())

                                .catch((err: Response) => {
                                  console.log((err.statusText || "Invalid Otp"));
                                  reject((err.statusText || "Invalid Otp"));
                                  reject((err.statusText || "Exhausted 3 attempts for OTP to activate member"));
                                  return Observable.throw(err);
                                })

                                .subscribe(
                                    data => {
                                    console.log(data);
                                    resolve(data);
                                    if(data="Invalid Otp"){
                                        alert(data);
                                        window.location.reload();
                                      //  this.myHome(fm);
                                    }
                                    else {
                                    alert(data);
                                this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);                          
                        }
                                },
                                err => {
                                    console.log("ERROR:  quote-service:myHome()")
                                    console.log(err);
                                    alert(err._body);
                                }
                            );
                            });
                }                           
                }
```

Comment: You cannot reload the same page, just reset the error messages and other things if you want to refresh.

Comment: I have tried window.location.reload(); in if block. You can try your code in if and else block.

Comment: is it working in real device? there is no concept of page refresh in ionic. you should manually reset the page on if-else condition